# How to execute the cdeconvert app from OS X or XCode7?

Tags: ensembles

I found the *cdeconvert* app, got a clean build and then the error about not passing the file path.  Sorry for the lame question, but I have never built/run an OS X app from XCode directly.  Question is: how do I execute (either from XCode or OS X directly) *cdeconvert* passing the *cdeevent* file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cdeconvert is a command line tool. Once it is built, you can locate the executable file (in Products), and use it via the command line. There is no app.

Comment: Got it working, thank you for the help... One related question:  is there a way to *decode* the different elements?  (I see the *change types* and it would be of great help to see which record they were referring to).

Comment: No, because it is possible that this depends on classes in your app, which CDEConvert can't access. Ie it uses NSCoding, and not all the classes may be present.